# Smd footprint Altium

Tags: pcb, altium, pcb-layers, footprint

[image]I'm trying to make the footprint of a smd resistor. But when I place the resistor on pcb layout and flip it, the pads go on bottom layer but the body remains on top layer, viewing from 3D mode. Instead the standard footprints work properly. Why this happen?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of the footprint in the editor?

Comment: Did you add the 3D body to the part or to the layout?  If it's with the part, I've never seen Altium do this...what version are you running?

Comment: Maybe I add it to the layout. I'm a beginner with this software. The version is 14.1

Comment: Are you placing the 3D body on the correct layer? It's likely Mechanical Layer 13. Altium has layer pairs that it associates with top/bottom. Check if your layer pairs are set up correctly.

Comment: Ok thanks. By the way I used the wrong layer. I put it on mechanical layer 13 and the problem was solved.

Comment: @Psy if the problem is solved then either accept DerStrom8's answer or put your last comment as an answer then accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally Mechanical 1 is used for 3D bodies on the top layer and Mechanical 13 is used for 3D bodies on the bottom layer. I always design my parts looking at the top layer, so my 3D models always go on Mechanical 1.

When you want to put a component on the bottom layer, do not "flip it" (assuming you mean using the 'X' key). Instead you select the part and in the properties change it from "Top Layer" to "Bottom Layer". If I remember correctly, Eagle moved components from the top to bottom by "flipping" them, but this is not the correct way to do it in Altium.

Comment: No. I use the L key to put the component on bottom/top layer.